# Automatically lock my Linux computer when I walk away from it

Tags: linux, security, devices, lock

I would like to lock my Linux (GNOME) machine after I walk away from it. Ideally, it should be a small Bluetooth tag / card that I carry in my pocket with a proximity sensor.

Is there some software and hardware that I can use for Linux for this purpose?

Basically, I'm looking for something like GateKeeper (*but I don't know if this works for Linux*) https://technabob.com/blog/2014/03/19/gatekeeper-locks-pc-automatically/

> The proximity feature will automatically lock and unlock your PC or Mac when you walk away from it. That will keep your machine from sitting unprotected.